# turn off android camera in flashcs6 adobe air

Tags: java, android, actionscript-3, air, flash-cs6

**Hi guys**

i  need turn off camera in android app created by adobe air 3 in flash cs6 .

i used this code for turn off camera :

**`videoDetect.attachCamera(null);
videoCapture.attachCamera(null);`**

but when run in my device , error :

```
   An error has occurred in sub: settingm_camera1_ready
    (java line: 464)
    java.lang.IllegalStateException:The specified child already has a parent.you must call removeView() on the child s parent first.
```

plz help .

tanx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try the following:

```
video.attachCamera(null);
video.clear();
removeChild(_video);
camera = null;
```